# How to fix "Cannot invoke 'send' with no arguments" in Swift 5.1

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I've been trying to follow the 'Introducing SwiftUI - Building Your First App' WWDC 19 video. No sample code is provided for this talk but I've been creating it as the presenter goes along. When trying to create a store though I get an  error that 'Cannot invoke 'send' with no arguments' from the line:

```
didSet { didChange.send() }
```

I'm new to programming and struggling to troubleshoot.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ReferenceStore : BindableObject {
    var references: [Reference] {
        didSet { didChange.send() }
    }

    init(references: [Reference] = []) {
        self.references = references
    }

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

I'm using Xcode 11 beta and MacOS Catalina if it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>` is your publisher, and it's declared as:

```swift
final class PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure> where Failure : Error
```

And this is `send` function:

```swift
final func send(_ input: Output)
```

That means `send` needs a `Void` argument, which in Swift is the empty tuple `()`.

Replace:

`didChange.send()`

with

`didChange.send(())`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code to

```
class ReferenceStore : BindableObject {
    var references: [Reference] {
        didSet { didChange.send(self) }
    }

    init(references: [Reference] = []) {
        self.references = references
    }

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<ReferenceStore, Never>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Xcode 11 beta 4**, you can just use [send()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject/3326007-send) instance method.

```
func send()
```

Usage :

```
var references: [Reference] {
    didSet { didChange.send() }
}
```

**Update** :

> The `BindableObject` protocol’s requirement is now **willChange**
>   instead of **didChange**, and should now be sent before the object
>   changes rather than after it changes. This change allows for improved
>   coalescing of change notifications.

So change your code to

```
class ReferenceStore : BindableObject {
    var references: [Reference] {
        didSet { willChange.send() }
    }

    init(references: [Reference] = []) {
        self.references = references
    }

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```